# How to export a named instance of a class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node project, I have the following code.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import config from 'config';

class UserService {
   generateAuthToken(user) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin }, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
      return token;
   }
}

export new UserService();
```

This gives me unexpected token error. But if I set it as follows it works.

```
 export default new UserService();
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Export default is used by a simple require/import where you dont tell it exactly what you want to import https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export new UserService();` throws an Error because when using named exports, `export` expects an identifier and `new UserService()` does not resolve to a valid identifier.

Try this:

```
export const userService = new UserService();

/** imported like this: */
import { userService } from '../../the-path'
```

So, the name of identifier MUST be the same when you `import` a named export.
If you change the export identifier name, you must change that in import as well:

```
export const service = new UserService(); // <- just service

/** imported like this: */
import { service } from '../../the-path' // <- userService would be undefined. you have to import service
```

Unlike named exports, default does not have restrictions on the name while importing.

For example:

```
export default new UserService();

/** while importing, */
import userService from '../../the-path'; // <- works!
import serviceOfUser from '../../the-path'; // <- Works!
```

---

Read more about `export` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)